# ldlinux.bss ldlinux.sys installation

Tags: boot-repair, syslinux, rufus

i have formated my computer by using bootable usb that i have created with rufus program.
when creating the usb the rufus sent a massage that the ldlinux.sys and ldlinux.bss files are not included and that the system will repair if she have them available.

how do i install those files after having the ubuntu running already?

i have found some answers to this problem that include making a new bootable usb and i was wondering if there is any way to insert those files to the running operating system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These files are for the installation media **only**. If you managed to install Ubuntu, then they are not needed, because they aren't required for the installed OS.

In other words, the live system that runs the installer **might** need these files to boot. But if it booted, and you were able to install the system, then you don't need to care, because these files don't apply to the installed OS. Especially they aren't even needed to install the final OS bootloader, if that's your concern. They're just potentially needed so that the USB boots, and that's it.

I'm not sure why you think you need to do something about these files after you installed the OS. The message you saw from Rufus should imply that these files are only needed for the bootable USB and not the final installed OS.